# How can I make animation with objects

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation, frameworks

I am a new frontend developer,and there was a cool animation made with objects in the Samsung Galaxy Buds Live website where when I scroll down it keeps displaying different frames of the buds revolving until it stop,so I want to know how to make them or what languages other than (html,css,javascript) or frameworks I need to make something like that

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Hi' start with CSS animation and grow from there
you can read this
[CSS Animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations)

Comment: Thanks,sir.But is there something related to the objects uesd themselves not their animation?

Comment: maybe the 3D, check this one https://spline.design/